# NX Daemon process terminated and closed the connection and why do I need to delete cache?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, caching, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

I initialized my project using NX and set a preset for Angular. While trying to open it locally (nx serve), I get the error:

NX   Daemon process terminated and closed the connection

Please rerun the command, which will restart the daemon.
If you get this error again, check for any errors in the daemon process logs found in: C:...nx\cache\d\daemon.log

Where it tells me to delete angular cache :

"To fix this, set a unique name for each project in a project.json inside the project's root. If the project does not currently have a project.json, you can create one that contains only a name.
Error: The following projects are defined in multiple locations:

- undefined:

  - .angular/cache/17.1.4/vite/deps
  - .angular/cache/17.1.4/vite/deps_temp_94f779ee
  - .angular/cache/17.1.4/vite/deps_temp_c64f8585"

And it works but I have to delete cache everytime it happens locally through VSC. Is there a reason why this happens, how may I approach this without deleting cache everytime?